# Add elements to a Stage from a different controller

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml

I have a `MainInterface.fxml`, with its own controller `MainController` in which a button opens a new Stage from `NewCrawler.fxml` with its associated controller `AddCrawlerController`.
 It looks fine, but i need to add stuff into the MainInterface using the interface NewCrawler .

The goal is adding a new  "itemCrawler" each time someone press the "Start Crawling" button in NewCrawler, like the one hardcoded in MainInterface. How Can I do that?

MainController.java

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML private AnchorPane mainPane;

    @FXML
    public void addCrawlerInstance(String domain) { //TODO dynamically add itemCrawler (Like the one hardcoded in MainInterface
        Button b = new Button(domain); //it is only a try to add elements from a different controller
        mainPane.getChildren().add(b);
    }

    @FXML
    private void createCrawler () throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("guifxml/NewCrawler.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }



}
```

AddCrawlerController.java

```
public class AddCrawlerController { //ADD Button from Main Interface
    @FXML private Button abortButton;
    @FXML private Button addCrawlerButton;

    @FXML
    private void abortCurrentWindow () {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) abortButton.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    private void addNewCrawler () throws Exception { //TODO ref. Maincontroller.AddCrawlerInstance
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("guifxml/MainInterface.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        String d = "prova";
        MainController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.addCrawlerInstance("prova");
    }
}
```

MainInterface.fxml

```
<VBox fx:id="mainApp" maxWidth="600.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="wsa.gui.MainController">
  <children>
      <ButtonBar maxWidth="643.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="643.0">
        <buttons>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Path" />
          <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stop" />
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" />
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#createCrawler" text="Add" />
        </buttons>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin>
         <padding>
            <Insets right="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </ButtonBar>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Separator layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="645.0" />
            <Pane fx:id="itemCrawler" prefHeight="52.0" prefWidth="645.0">
               <children>
                  <Text layoutX="44.0" layoutY="34.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Domain">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <TextField editable="false" layoutX="124.0" layoutY="13.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="319.0" text="http://www.prova.org" />
                  <Button alignment="CENTER" layoutX="456.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add URI" />
                  <Button alignment="CENTER" layoutX="528.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Explore" />
                  <CheckBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="18.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="17.0" />
                  <Separator layoutY="51.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="645.0" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

NewCrawler.fxml

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="wsa.gui.AddCrawlerController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextArea layoutX="119.0" layoutY="89.0" prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="467.0" />
      <Text layoutX="44.0" layoutY="52.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Domain" wrappingWidth="74.13671875">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <TextField layoutX="119.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="467.0" />
      <Text layoutX="44.0" layoutY="111.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="URI list" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="74.13672208786011">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text layoutX="119.0" layoutY="85.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="one URI on each line " textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="467.00000166893005" />
      <Button fx:id="addCrawlerButton" layoutX="260.0" layoutY="353.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="115.0" onMouseClicked="#addNewCrawler" text="Start Crawling" />
      <Button fx:id="abortButton" layoutX="118.0" layoutY="353.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#abortCurrentWindow" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="Abort" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[MainInterface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrzlA.png)
[NewCrawler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqyd4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you need a dynamic list of itemCrawlers.

Instead of hardcoding a newCrawler, you should use a `ListView` with a custom `CellFactory` that constructs custom `ListCell` to represent itemCrawler.

This tutorial tells you how to do that : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this, so correct me if I am wrong.

In the NewCrawler's controller you load the FXML in its constructor. Then you can instantiate the NewCrawler controller and work with it as with any other object inside your MainController.